# Boxes inline with unordered list, bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want two boxes with different content in them. I want them to line up at top. Default they line up with bottom http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9772/

How do I get them at top instead of bottom?

```
<ul class="list-inline">
 <li class="box">
     <ul>
         <li>
              aaa
         </li>
          <li>
              aaa
         </li>
     </ul>

 </li>
 <li class="box">
     <ul>
         <li>
              aaa
         </li>
          <li>
              aaa
         </li>
         <li>
              aaa
         </li>
     </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: a simplest way is to assign a vertical-align to box: `.box{
    width:200px;
    background:#ccc;
  vertical-align: top;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to vertically align the initial list items. Add the CSS (or rather, combine with the current rule):

```
.box{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9776/)

Note that your HTML is also invalid, you need to ensure you are correctly closing each `li`